# dump selected data from one db to another in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**Here's the situation:**

I have a mySQL db on a remote server. I need data from 4 of its tables. On occasion, the schema of these tables is changed (new fields are added, but not removed). At the moment, the tables have > 300,000 records.

This data needs to be imported into the localhost mySQL instance. These same 4 tables exist (with the same names), but the fields needed are a subset of the fields in the remote db tables. The data in these local tables is considered read-only and is never written to. Everything needs to be run in a transaction so there is always some data in the local tables, even if it is a day old. The localhost tables are used by an active website, so this entire process needs to complete as quickly as possible to minimize downtime.

This process runs once per day.

**The options as I see them:**

1. Get a mysqldump of the structure/data of the remote tables and save to file. Drop the localhost tables, and run the dumped sql script. Then recreate the needed indexes on the 4 tables.
2. Truncate the localhost tables. Run SELECT queries on the remote db in PHP and retrieve only the fields needed instead of the entire row. Then loop through the results and create INSERT statements from this data.

**My questions:**

- Performance wise, which is my best option?
- Which one will complete the fastest?
- Will either one put a heavier load on the server?
- Would indexing the
  tables take the same amount of time in both options?

Comment: if it's an option, look into active mirroring using mysql, or even something along the lines of redis - worth looking into anyways.

Comment: @damianb - I'm not familiar with active mirroring. Could you elaborate?

Comment: i should have said database replication, apologies. :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no good reason for having the local d/b be a subset of the remote, make the structure the same and enable [database replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) on the needed tables.  Replication works by the master tracking all changes made, and managing each slave d/b's pointer into the changes.  Each slave says *give me all changes since the last request*.  For a sizeable database, this is far more efficient than any alternative you have selected.  It comes with only modest cost.

As for schema changes, I think the `alter` information is logged by the master, so the slave(s) can replicate those as well.  The mechanism definitely replicates [`drop table ... if exists`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-features-drop-if-exists.html) and [`create table ... select`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-features-create-select.html), so `alter` logically should follow, but I have not tried it.

---

Here it is:  [confirmation that `alter` is properly replicated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-features-auto-increment.html).

Comment: The local db is actually a Drupal db and these 4 tables are being used by a custom Drupal module. So unless replication supports this type of scenario, your suggestion isn't going to work.

Comment: Well, the wording in the question says *import into the localhost mySQL instance* and does not mention Drupal.  Undoubtedly Drupal can be customized to work with active replicated data, but that could range from trivial to nearly impossible depending on the specifics.